Grafana Instant query for prometheus metric not working
I'm try to get the latest value for kube_job_status_completion_time Prometheus metric using a Grafana query. My query is last_over_time(kube_job_status_completion_time{job_name=~".*ingestion-job.*"}[14s]).
EDIT: Solution was to use put a bigger time range instead of "14s". I could build a query showing duration of jobs on the last 7 days avg by (job_name) (last_over_time(kube_job_status_completion_time{job_name=~".*ingestion-job.*"}[7d]) - last_over_time(kube_job_status_start_time{job_name=~".*ingestion-job.*"}[7d]))
When I execute the query in Prometheus directly, in range mode I get single values
Graph showing single values in Prometheus, as expected
When I enter the query in Grafana in range mode I get multiple values
Graph showing multiple values in Grafana, not expected
=> Am I missing something ? How to make Grafana return only latest value ?
I tried multiple things, including changing the min step, trying range mode, changing specified interval, tried some hacky solution (adding left join in query), I read some doc https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#range-vector-selectors ...
UPDATE: Could it be because I'm running both metrics-server and kube-prometheus-node-exporter ?
UPDATE 2: Regarding the timestamp, I understand the logic behind:

As soon as job finishes, the metric "kube_job_status_completion_time" exists and is scrapped
Since the ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 600 is 10 minutes, the metric is scrapped during 10 minutes every scrape_interval: 30s
When the ttlSecondsAfterFinished is reached, the metric is not scrapped anymore
Note: depending on the time range I set in Grafana, I get more of less values of these 20 values available (if I look for last 7 days only few values are displayed, if I look for last hours, all 20 values are displayed).

But I still don't get how to get only ONE of these values !
here are exported results:
"Time","__name__","container","endpoint","instance","job","job_name","namespace","pod","service","Value"
1716473190000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473220000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473250000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473280000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473310000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473340000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473370000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473400000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473430000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473460000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473490000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473520000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473550000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473580000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473610000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473640000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473670000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473700000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473730000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161
1716473760000,kube_job_status_completion_time,kube-state-metrics,http,10.0.0.21:8080,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,ingestion-job-53232587-6e2e-47e3-92b2-eff278e8ba4e,default,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-5cb664f67-zpqx6,kube-prometheus-kube-state-metrics,1716473161


That is strange. Are all the labels the same for your 10 entries that are returned from grafana?

yes there are the same, I exported the results and added it to my post

What do you actually mean with "labels" ?

When you select format Table for query, Grafana's explore page shows data points without timestamps.

I don't fully get what you intention here, but usually to get a single value you'd need to choose type Instant. And maybe wrap metric with last_over_time to extend last value, though I doubt 14s in your attempt do much. Usually range there is, let's say more substantial.

thanks for the hint ! Now I put "7 days" and it looks better. I could now build a query that calculates the duration of completed jobs in the last 7 days.
avg by (job_name) (last_over_time(kube_job_status_completion_time{job_name=~".*ingestion-job.*"}[7d]) - last_over_time(kube_job_status_start_time{job_name=~".*ingestion-job.*"}[7d]))
